# Did Maa Saraswati help manthara convince Kaikayi?

Tags: ramayana, rama

Is it true that Maa Saraswati helped manthara convince Kaikayi by poisoning her mind and seek the throne for Bharat coz else Rama not knowing what was the purpose of his birth would have ruled as king of Ayodhya for as long as he would have wanted?

In other words can we say that when Gods are born in human form (incarnation) they forgot the purpose of their birth and things have to be manipulated to make them do what they were supposed to do in that birth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's true as per [Ramcharitmanas: Ayodhya Kanda: 11-12](https://archive.org/stream/RamcharitmanasGitapressEnglish/Ramcharitmanas%20Gitapress%20English#page/n377/mode/1up)

Here are few relevant chopais, Dohas:

> **सारद** बोलि बिनय सुर करहीं। बारहिं बार पाय लै परहीं।।
>
> Invoking **Sharda (Maa Saraswati)** the gods supplicated her and laying hold of her feet fell at them again and again.
>
> बिपति हमारि बिलोकि बड़ि मातु करिअ सोइ आजु।
>
> रामु जाहिं बन राजु तजि होइ सकल सुरकाजु।।11।।
>
> Perceiving our grave calamity, O Mother, manipulate things in such a way today
>   that Shri Rama may retire into the forest, relinquishing His throne, and the object of us immortals may be wholly accomplished.
>
> नामु मंथरा मंदमति चेरी कैकेइ केरि।
>
> अजस पेटारी ताहि करि गई [गिरा](https://shabdkosh.raftaar.in/Meaning-of-%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE-in-Hindi) मति फेरि।।12।।
>
> Kaikeyi had a dull-witted servant-maid, Manthara by name; having perverted her reason and making her a receptacle of ill-repute, **the goddess of speech** (Maa Saraswati) returned to her abode.

Comment: Where does it mention Maa Saraswati?

Comment: @Just_Do_It it mention Sharda which means Maa Saraswati...

Comment: @YDS So can we say that when Gods are born in human form (incarnation) they forgot the purpose of their birth and things have to be manipulated to make them do what they were supposed to do in that birth?

Comment: @Just_Do_It Seems partially true...for example, Lord Brahma tried to explain Rama that he is an incarnation of Vishnu several times (Yudhkanda , Uttarakhand) in Valmiki Ramayana...but in Ramcharitmanas it seems after a certain point Rama was aware of his divinity...as both the scriptures might tell stories of different Rama (from diff Kalpa/Manvanta/Yuga) so may be sometimes Rama was aware of his divinity and sometimes not...For Krishna we don't find much about someone trying to explain him about his divinity even he explained to others several times...So partially true, or sometimes true...

Answer (score 0):

As per Mahabharata. Manthara happened to be an incarnation of Gandharva by the name of Dundubhi, who followed directions from Lord Brahma

From Mahabharata's [Vana Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03274.htm)

> And at this, the gods, the Gandharvas and the Danavas quickly assembled to take counsel as to how they should be born on earth according to their respective parts. And in their presence the boon-giving god commanded a Gandharvi, by name Dundubhi saying, 'Go there for accomplishing this object!' And Dundubhi hearing these words of the Grandsire was born in the world of men as the hunchbacked Manthara

And then

> And the adorable Creator of the Universe, having ordained all this, instructed Manthara as to what she would have to do. And Manthara quick as thought, understood all his words, and went hither and thither ever engaged in fomenting quarrels.

So as seen here she was following directions from Lord Brahma.